# Javascript Converting Object Keys To Images

Tags: javascript

Sample object:

```
images {"foo":"bar.jpg",...}
```

How to convert this object as list of Image files to use like,

```
ctx.drawImage(images.foo,x,y)
```

without creating a new object?

Comment: Can you give a little more explanation? What do you mean "without creating a new object"? Directly mutate the images object? So you want to end up with the images object full of images instead of a new one?

Comment: @AlexanderVitanov Yes I wanted to directly mutate keys. Is there a way to dot it?

Comment: Yes, answer coming

Comment: @AlexanderVitanov Thank you.

Comment: @hello_guys ... you don't need to worry about any voting direction if your Q shows some effort in solving the problem or even better describing the matter more precise.

Comment: Just fyi @hello_guys, it helps people if you explain what you tried and what errors your attempt provoked as part of your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seeing as you said in the comments that you want this to occur in a function, and that you want the image paths to be mutated into objects of the `Image` type, I think this is what you are looking for:

```
var images = { "foo": "bar.jpg" };

function transformImagePaths(images){
    Object.keys(images).forEach(key => {
        let imagePath = images[key];
        images[key] = new Image();
        images[key].src = imagePath;
    });
}
```

When you pass the `images` object to the function, it will loop over its keys, and reassign each key by replacing the path with the an image.

Answer (score 0):

One way to do it:

```
var images = { "foo": "bar.jpg" }
for (var imageKey in images) {
   images[imageKey] = ctx.drawImage(images[imageKey],x,y)
}
```

Comment: Thank you for this guidance. But the object variable is a global and I need to mutate the keys to Images inside a function for elegance then I will draw them in another function.

Comment: So we are talking about the out of the box Image component from React Native, is that correct?

Comment: As I understand without creating new global object it is impossible to achieve in pure Javascript.

Comment: @AlexanderVitanov ... another, maybe more preferable approach, was making use of `Object.keys` or, if available, even `Object.entries`.

Comment: @hello_guys In JavaScript objects are passed as references so you can just place the for loop inside a function, pass the object "images" into said function, and it will mutate the keys without creating a new object.

Comment: @Jonah with `for (key in obj)`  `key = new Image(); key.src = obj[key];` not achiving this.

Comment: @hello_guys ... of cause not since your code does assign an `Image` type to `key`, thus `key.src = obj[key];`won't work correctly.

Comment: @PeterSeliger Thank you Peter. How can I achieve this in a for loop in proper way?

Comment: @hello_guys ... [see my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46915059/javascript-converting-object-keys-to-images#46915735)

Answer (score 0):

```js
// first proving approach
var imageMap = {
  "foo": "bar.jpg",
  "baz": "biz.jpg"
};
console.log('imageMap : ', imageMap);

Object.keys(imageMap).forEach(function (imageKey) {
  var img = (new Image);
  img.src = imageMap[imageKey];
  imageMap[imageKey] = img;
});
console.log('imageMap : ', imageMap);


// final iteration
var imageMap = {
  "foo": "bar.jpg",
  "baz": "biz.jpg"
};
console.log('imageMap : ', imageMap);

function assignImageToBoundMap(key) {
  var img   = (new Image);
  img.src   = this[key];
  this[key] = img;
}
function reassignImageMap(map) {
  Object.keys(map).forEach(assignImageToBoundMap, map);
}

reassignImageMap(imageMap);

console.log('imageMap : ', imageMap);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100%!important; top: 0; }
```